# How to configure Quickbooks online API to work with multiple users/company?

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

Currently I have configured Quickbooks online API functionality for single user. which gets customers/bill information from quickbooks online using OAuth. It is working perfect.

I want to do the same functionality for multiple users.

Now there are many user's of quickbooks who have their own quickbooks online accounts and all these users are present in my custom application.

Is it possible to setup API functionality using keithe palmar's dev kit for different users to have API access? which things needs to be configured to make it run?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to setup API functionality using keithe palmar's dev kit for different users to have API access?

Yes.

> which things needs to be configured to make it run?

There is a variable `$the_tenant` that needs to be unique to each separate QuickBooks Online company you want to connect.

If you're building a multi-tenant type SaaS app, then you probably have a unique identifier for each of YOUR tenants already. So, set `$the_tenant` to your unique tenant ID value.

Done. That's all you have to do.

Relevant code:

```
// The tenant that user is accessing within your own app
$the_tenant = 12345;
```

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/config.php#L57

All of the OAuth stuff is stored/based on that `$the_tenant` variable, so just make sure it's set to your unique tenant ID, and you're good to go. Note that you'll have to connect each individual QuickBooks company separately.

Comment: Thanks Keith! as per your suggestion I have changed the tenant id and it is working perfect.